# Variation of $f(k)=(k-k^2c)\frac{\Gamma(L-k,ak+b)}{\Gamma(L-k)}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, functions, derivatives

I have the following function: $f(k)=(k-k^2c)\frac{\Gamma(L-k,ak+b)}{\Gamma(L-k)}$, with $kc <1$, and $a, b$ are some positive constants. We assume that $1\le k\le L-1$. Note that $\Gamma(s,x)=\int_x^\infty t^{s-1}e^{-t}dt$ and $\Gamma(s)=\int_0^\infty t^{s-1}e^{-t}dt$. Also note that $k$ represents an integer value.

Is there any way to analyse the variation of function $f(k)$ ? (this is the main question)

Also, how $\frac{\Gamma(L-k,ak+b)}{\Gamma(L-k)}$ changes  with $k$ ?

P.S.: I have no idea how to derive this function, so I did not put any attempt.

Comment: Take a look at this rule https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign